# How do I export labels as editable text objects to be used in Illustrator?

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, text

How do I export labels as editable text objects to be used in Illustrator? QGIS 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS 1.8, only the old labeling engine (in layer properties - labels) is exported as text to SVG. The new labels which can be added using the labeling toolbar are exported as SVG paths.

It seems like the behavior is still the same in 2.0.1. There is a feature request to change it: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3975